# FSEvents- Detect type of event on the folder

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Any Idea on how to detect type of folder event(FSEvent) raised in the folder in the callback method (gotEvent method in below code)? Ex: File Renamed, File Created? I want to do some operation only with File Renamed, File Created. Want to ignore other events.

I have below implementation -

```
- (FSEventStreamRef) eventStreamForFileAtPath: (NSString *) fileInputPath  {

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileInputPath]) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"FileNotFoundException"
                                       reason:@"There is not file at path specified in fileInputPath"
                                     userInfo:nil];
    }

    NSString *fileInputDir = [fileInputPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

    NSArray *pathsToWatch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileInputDir, nil];

    void *appPointer = (__bridge void *)self;

    FSEventStreamContext context = {0, appPointer, NULL, NULL, NULL};

    NSTimeInterval latency = 3.0;

    FSEventStreamRef stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                                  &gotEvent,
                                                  &context,
                                                  (__bridge CFArrayRef) pathsToWatch,
                                                  kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                                                  (CFAbsoluteTime) latency,
                                                  kFSEventStreamCreateFlagUseCFTypes
                                                  );

    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(stream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    FSEventStreamStart(stream);

    return stream;

}

static void gotEvent(ConstFSEventStreamRef stream,
                     void *clientCallBackInfo,
                     size_t numEvents,
                     void *eventPathsVoidPointer,
                     const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                     const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]
                     ) {

    NSLog(@"File Changed!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FSEventStreamEventFlags` should indicate what happened, according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html):

> kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated = 0x00000100,
>   kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRemoved = 0x00000200,
>   kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed = 0x00000800,
>   kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified = 0x00001000,

Evaluating which flag is set should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I have been searching for the actual implementation. Finally, here is what I have implemented which gets the events ----                
    FSEventStreamEventFlags flags = eventFlags[0];
    
    if (flags & kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated)
    {
         NSLog(@"File Created!");
    }
    else if (flags & kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed)
    {
         NSLog(@"File Renamed!");
    }
    else if (flags & kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRemoved)
    {
        NSLog(@"File Removed!");
    }

Comment: How do you get the above code to work in swift though? Trying to figure it out.